# Factorization of polynomial in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

I want to show that $x^2-14$ doesn't factorize into $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ in $Z_{2014}$

Since $ac=1$ , $x=c^{-1}(-b)$ or $x=a^{-1}(-d)$ is one of the solution "$f(x)=0$" where $f(x)=x^2-14$ and those are in $Z_{2014}$

So if we verify there is no one $x$ s.t. $x^2\equiv14 (mod\ 2014)$ then it is end.

But 2014 is so big! Anyone can prove this?

And generally, is there a nice conclusion of polynomial factorization in a ring?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2014=2\cdot 19\cdot 53$.  So to have a solution to $x^2\equiv 14 \pmod{2014}$, you would need $x$ to satisfy $x^2\equiv 14$ relative to each of the moduli $2, 19$, and $53$.

Comment: Then , what I need is just calculation? Isn't there a general method to confirm that f(x) can factorize into g(x)h(x) in a ring?

Comment: Since in your case you just have to deal with equations of the type $x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$ for some prime $p$, you might be interested in the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) to speed up computation, but this is really more advanced maths. Look in particular at the computational example at the end of the article.